# C++ list/vector help

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ so this is probably a very simple question, but I haven't been able to find any examples online that have helped.

I've defined my own `Bubble` class and I need to create a `vector`/`list` (I'm used to C# and Java, so I'm not sure which is correct) to dynamically store `Bubble` objects in. Here's my code so far:

```
#include "Bubble.h"
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int backgroundImages[10]; 
list<Bubble> bubbles;
vector<Bubble> bubbles_two;
Bubble b;

void AppMain()
{
    loadImages();
    ViewAdd(backgroundImages[8], 0,0);
    b = Bubble();
    b.velocity = Vector2D(9,4);

    //I know this can't be right..
    bubbles.add(b);
    bubbles_two.add(b);
}
```

Neither the `list` nor the `vector` works - it says "list/vector is not a template" in my error list.

Which should I use, `list` or `vector`? And how do I correctly implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functions vector.add() and list.add() do not exist.

```
#include "Bubble.h"
#include <vector>
#include <list>

int backgroundImages[10]; 
std::list<Bubble> bubbles(); // use the std namespace and instantiate it
std::vector<Bubble> bubbles_two(); // same here
Bubble b;

void AppMain()
{
    loadImages();
    ViewAdd(backgroundImages[8], 0,0);
    b = Bubble();
    b.velocity = Vector2D(9,4);

    //I know this can't be right..
    bubbles.push_back(b); // std::list also defines the method push_front
    bubbles_two.push_back(b);
}
```

There are almost no obvious differences between the vector and the list, but functionally, there are.

> Compared to the other base standard
>   sequence containers (deques and
>   lists), vectors are generally the most
>   efficient in time for accessing
>   elements and to add or remove elements
>   from the end of the sequence. For
>   operations that involve inserting or
>   removing elements at positions other
>   than the end, they perform worse than
>   deques and lists, and have less
>   consistent iterators and references
>   than lists.
>
> Compared to other base standard
>   sequence containers (vectors and
>   deques), lists perform generally
>   better in inserting, extracting and
>   moving elements in any position within
>   the container, and therefore also in
>   algorithms that make intensive use of
>   these, like sorting algorithms.

Comment: "almost no obvious differences"? How about random access with []/::at? That's the most obvious distinction between the two, and it's not something you can really ignore when picking one or the other.

Answer (score 5):

They are in the `std` namespace. As are all parts of the C++ standard library. So they are correctly called `std::list` and `std::vector`.

They also don't have member functions called `add`. You may want to look up a [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/).

Answer (score 4):

Vector and list are part of the std namespace. So you should declare your vector and your list like this:

```
std::list<Bubble> bubbles;
std::vector<Bubble> bubbles_two;
```

Also, the member function to add an element is push_back.

Answer (score 2):

`list` and `vector` are in the `std` namespace, and you accordingly must look for them there.

`std::vector<Bubble> bubbles;`

In either case, you use `.push_back` to append to the container. When in doubt, you should generally prefer `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the namespace here. Both list and vector is part of the standard namespace which Means that you can include the namespace on a global basis by writing `using namespace std;` once in the beginning of the file or write `std::list` and `std::vector` every where you are using the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
std::list<Bubble> bubbles;
std::vector<Bubble> bubbles_two;
```

Lists and vectors are defined in the `std` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>  //Desouky//
using namespace std;
struct node
{
int data;
node* link= NULL;
};
int main()
{

freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
node* head = new node;
node*temp = new node;
head = temp;
int x;
cin >> x;
temp->data = x;
while (cin >> x)
{
    node* temp1 = new node;
    temp1->data = x;
    temp->link = temp1;
    temp = temp->link;
}
temp = head;

while (temp != NULL)
{
    cout << temp->data << " ";
    temp = temp->link;
}
}
```